# Suppose that $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is a onto function and $A \subseteq X$ then $Y\setminus f(A) \subseteq f(X\setminus A)$.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

Let $A, X, Y$  be sets. Suppose that $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is an onto function and $A \subseteq X.$ Then $Y\setminus f(A) \subseteq f(X\setminus A)$.

My definition of onto (surjective) is "A function $f:X \rightarrow Y$ is said to be onto (or surjective) provided that for each $y \in Y$ there exists at least one $x \in X$ such that $f(x) = y$

This is a true statement so I will proof it.

Begin with let $ y \in Y \setminus f(A)$ then $y \in Y$ and $ y \notin f(A).$ By defintion of onto there exists an $x \in X$ such that $f(x) = y$

I just don't know where to go from here I really think I am on the right track. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Take any $y^* \in Y-f(A)$.  Since $f(A) - y: \exists x \in A : f(x) - y$, and $y*$ is not in $f(A)$, there is no $x \in A : f(x) = y^*$. (I use the symbol ":" for "such that.")

Now suppose $Y - f(A)$ is not a subset of $f(X-A)$; then there is some $y^* \in Y-f(A) : y^* \not\in f(X-A)$. But since $f$ is surjective, $\exists x^* \in X: f(x^*) = y^*$.

And since $y^* \not\in f(X-A)$, there is no $x \in X-A : y^* = f(x)$. So $x^*$ can't be in $X-A$, hence $x^* \in A$. So $y = f(x^*) : x^* \in A$, which implies that $y^* \in f(A)$. 
But we already had $y^* \in Y-f(A) $, thus we have a contradiction arising from the starting point that  $Y - f(A)$ is not a subset of $f(X-A)$.

So
$Y - f(A) \subseteq f(X-A)$.

Comment: what does * mean?

Answer (score 0):

let $ y \in Y \setminus f(A)$ then $y \in Y$ and $ y \notin f(A).$ By defintion of *onto*, there exists an $x \in X$ such that $f(x) = y$
if $x \in A$ then $y=f(x) \in f(A)$; contradiction. so $x \notin A$. As $X=A\cup (X\setminus A)$, we have $x \in X\setminus A$.